# Call a function when addclass loop ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I have a function in jQuery which adds a class name to a div - there are 100 divs which randomly get the new class added - code below

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var $divs = $(".cardWrapper section > div:not(.flip)");
    $divs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length)).addClass('flip');
    if ($divs.length == 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 500);
```

What I am looking to do now, is once the last (e.g. 100th) div has had the new 'flip' class added I want to be able to perform a new function in jQuery - e.g. for examples sake here lets say I want to call alert("all done"); Is this possible? Please bear in mind the addclass 'flip' is random so I can't just check to see if the 100th div in the list has flip added - I need to know when the addclass flip function has performed its function 100 times...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you call your other function inside the `if` statement right after `clearInterval()`?

Comment: You are right... that does work! Doh! sorry folks... its late... brain meltdown!

Answer (score 0):

`addClass` is a synchronous method so you can call whatever code you want on the next line.

Comment: You mis-read it the same way i did. He isn't adding flip to all of them at once, it's happening in an interval. he needs to know when all 100 have been modified.